# Linker looking for symbols that will not be invoked

Tags: c++, linker

I have a small piece of code which is a simplified replication of a bigger problem I am facing:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void SomeOtherFunc ();

void Func ()
{
    SomeOtherFunc ();
}


int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello";

    return 0;
}
```

In this, the function *Func* is is invoking the function *SomeOtherFunc*. However, *Func* is not invoked by anyone.

When I am compiling this file, I am getting a linker error: Unresolved external symbol. It states that the definition of *SomeOtherFunc*, which is referenced in the function *Func* is not found.

My question boils down to who referenced *Func* which required the linker to look up *SomeOtherFunc*?

Or is that understanding itself incorrect. If it is incorrect, does that mean the linker will pull in all functions invoked from all functions even though the function will never be invoked?

Or am I missing some linker flag? This happens with both MSVC and g++.

Comment: For the compiler: there is a function `Func()` may called from another compilation unit, to have `Func()`, the function `SomeOtherFunc()` is needed.  
For the linker: `Func()` is accessible, `SomeOtherFunc()` is needed.  
If you define `static void Func() {...`, then the compiler can remove the unused `Func()` and do not need `SomeOtherFunc()`.

Comment: The linker links all compiled code. This compiled code references a function called `SomeOtherFunc`. No definition of it was linked. Fail.

Comment: Enable Link Time Optimization (LTO). On gcc/clan add `-flto`, then linker will be fine with this missing definition since `Func` will be optimized away.

Comment: Or make the function static, to show that nobody else can call it.

Answer (score 4):

> who referenced Func which required the linker to look up SomeOtherFunc?

Gcc is producing an ELF file. ELF file contains all *external* symbols. `func` is an external symbol. As such, the produced ELF file, be it executable or shared library, should have an external symbol `func`.

> does that mean the linker will pull in all functions invoked from all functions even though the function will never be invoked?

External ones, yes.

The question you *did not* ask:

> how to remove unreferenced function so that I do not get linker errors?

You can remove unused symbols:

```
g++ -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wl,--gc-sections main.cpp
```

You can compile with whole program with optimizations:

```
g++ -O -fwhole-program main.cpp
```

Answer (score 2):

> My question boils down to who referenced *Func* which required the linker to look up *SomeOtherFunc*?

No one. A reference is not needed. The compiler produced a compiled version of `Func()` because the definition exists. That compiled version needs a link to `SomeOtherFunc()`, so that is what the linker attempts to do.

There is no obligation on the toolchain to remove unused definitions. Many toolchains make this optimization available, though. Even when it is available, there are two tiers of optimization. The easier, and more likely to be enabled, tier is a compile-time optimization. However, this applies only to symbols with [internal linkage](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Internal_linkage) (which would be the case if, for example, `Func()` had been declared `static`). The harder tier is a link time optimization (LTO), which typically needs to be specifically enabled with compiler flags, such as `-flto`, and which might not be available.

*See also [the gcc LTO design overview](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/LTO-Overview.html).*

> Or is that understanding itself incorrect. If it is incorrect, does that mean the linker will pull in all functions invoked from all functions even though the function will never be invoked?

The linker does not "pull in" so much as "take in". It looks at everything the compiler produced and supplies the missing links. It doesn't start at `main` and pull in what that uses recursively. Rather, it collects all defined symbols with external linkage, then goes through the unlinked references and links those references to the definitions. If all references end up linked, then all is well. Otherwise, the linker emits the error you got.

The optimization that you want would come from a link time optimization that either eliminates defined symbols that lack references or that analyzes the reference graph from `main` to determine which definitions are needed. In either case, this is additional work beyond what a linker is required to do, but it would detect that `Func()` is not needed. The end result would eliminate the reference to `SomeOtherFunc()`, so the linker would not complain about that function being missing, *if link time optimizations are **available** and **enabled**.*